# MongoDB - aggregation lookup in array field does not order array of objects by index

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of `ObjectId` field in my document which I need to `lookup` via `aggregate`.

```
return await MenuModel.aggregate([
{
    $match: conditions
},
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: 'pages',
        localField: "pages",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "pages"
    }
},
{
    $limit: 1
}
]);
```

It is working fine and returns array of objects in `pages` field. But it does not follow the `pages` collection documents "_id" order.

For example,

```
{
.......
"pages": [ObjectId("647b14aec29a553ad6e8f286"), ObjectId("647b14a0c29a553ad6e8f278")],
.......
}
```

It returns the following result -

[image: Result]

The `pages` field does not have objects in original order. How can I have the `pages` array of objects that is ordered before lookup?

Comment: Will need to add a subpipeline to the $lookup that $sorts or do add a $sortArray operator in a subsequent $addFields stage